# Searching Paypal Transactions from classic (IPN endpoint) with new REST API app

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been using PayPal's IPN to handle transactions.  I wanted to build a invoice search tool to be able to search through older or current user payments for various reasons.  I spent some time today setting up the PayPal PHP REST API SDK to facilitate this and did the following.

- I created a new app on developer.paypal.com using my current account.
- I installed the latest (1.6.3) [PayPal PHP REST SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) via composer.
- I configured the sdk_config.ini with my **LIVE** client id and secret.
- I set the ini file's mode from sandbox to **LIVE**.
- I create an OAuthTokenCredential using my **LIVE** client id and secret.
- I generate an AccessToken via the OAuthTokenCredential object, which requires an instance of the config .

  ```
  $config = PayPal\Core\PayPalConfigManager::getInstance()->getConfigHashmap();
  $oauth_credential->getAccessToken($config);
  ```
- I create an ApiContext using the primed OAuthTokenCredential.

  ```
  $api_context = new PayPal\Rest\ApiContext($oauth_credential);
  ```
- I create a search object using a broad date span that I'm 100% sure should return results.

  ```
  $search = new PayPal\Api\Search(
     '{
        "start_invoice_date" : "2014-12-01 PST",
        "end_invoice_date" : "2015-01-01 PST",
        "page" : 1,
        "page_size" : 20,
        "total_count_required" : true
     }'
  );
  ```
- I then do an invoice search utilizing both my search object and API context

  ```
  $invoices = PayPal\Api\Invoice::search($search, $api_context);
  ```

There are no errors and everything runs fine. The issue is that I get no results back in the `$invoices` object.  It acts as if I just created a new account and have no invoices. I get the feeling I'm missing a setting somewhere, Used an inappropriate API call for what I want to do, or that I should be using one of their other APIs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the classic and REST architecture in PayPal works independently and cannot be always used together. For instance,  you cannot use `REST API` to [search](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-sale) for a transaction ran using `Classic API` and vice versa.

Comment: Would I be able to use Paypal's NVP API then?

Comment: More specifically do I use Paypals new developers.paypal site or do I setup NVP credentials using the classic site?